# MySQL Match Against match all words using multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build a photo search application. I'm having trouble implementing a ranking system for the search results. The main problem appears to stem from the fact that I need to search multiple tables, for an undefined number of search tokens. For example, if I have a URL that is, say https://mydomain.tld/photos/mexico/sunset, the application will split off all values after photos (which could be 1+ values, never 0, theoretically unlimited, but unlikely to be more than 2/3/4), convert them to a space-separated string, search and return relevant results.

The main problem is that if the title / description / country contains the word Mexico multiple times then this scores more highly, so those results will appear higher even if the word sunset does not appear at all. I would like it so that if all words are present then these results will score highest. Unfortunately the word sunset will never appear in the "Countries" field so it is always at a disadvantage.

Here are my CREATE TABLES statements.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `photos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `town` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `directory` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `width` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_photos_country` (`country`),
  KEY `fk_photos_directory` (`directory`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`description`,`town`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_photos_country` FOREIGN KEY (`country`) REFERENCES `countries` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_photos_directory` FOREIGN KEY (`directory`) REFERENCES `directories` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=536 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
 
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `two_char_country_code` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `three_char_country_code` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `two_char_country_code` (`two_char_country_code`),
  UNIQUE KEY `three_char_country_code` (`three_char_country_code`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_2` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=251 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

and here is my best attempt at a query so far

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description, p.town, c.name AS country, p.filename, d.name AS directory, p.width, p.height,
    IFNULL(cmt.cmt_count, 0) AS comment_count, IFNULL(fv.fave_count, 0) AS fave_count,
MATCH(p.title, p.description, p.town) AGAINST(?) AS pscore,
MATCH(c.name) AGAINST(?) AS cscore
FROM photos p
LEFT JOIN countries c ON c.Id = p.country
LEFT JOIN directories d ON p.directory = d.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT photo_id, COUNT(comment) AS cmt_count
    FROM photo_comments 
    GROUP BY photo_id
) AS cmt ON cmt.photo_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT photo_id, COUNT(user_id) AS fave_count
    FROM photo_faves
    GROUP BY photo_id
) AS fv ON fv.photo_id = p.id
WHERE MATCH(p.title, p.description, p.town) AGAINST(?) > 0
OR MATCH(c.name) AGAINST(?) > 0
ORDER BY (pscore + cscore) DESC, (pscore > 0 AND cscore > 0) DESC, pscore DESC, cscore DESC
```

I don't really care if the solution uses this idea or a completely different one.

Sample output from the query above when using argument `mexico sunset` as outlined in the question higher up:

```json
{
    "photos": [
        {
            "id": 316,
            "title": "Mexico City",
            "description": null,
            "town": "Mexico City",
            "country": "Mexico",
            "comment_count": 0,
            "fave_count": 0,
            "pscore": 9,
            "cscore": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 68,
            "title": "Mayan Calendar",
            "description": null,
            "town": "Mexico City",
            "country": "Mexico",
            "comment_count": 0,
            "fave_count": 0,
            "pscore": 4,
            "cscore": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 462,
            "title": "Street Scene",
            "description": null,
            "town": "Mexico City",
            "country": "Mexico",
            "comment_count": 0,
            "fave_count": 0,
            "pscore": 4,
            "cscore": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 144,
            "title": "Sunset",
            "description": null,
            "town": "Chamula",
            "country": "Mexico",
            "comment_count": 0,
            "fave_count": 0,
            "pscore": 4,
            "cscore": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see there are 4 results but the sunset picture is last because the others score higher by having multiple occurrences of the other search term. What I need is for results that match all search terms (ignoring duplicates?) to be ranked higher.

Comment: If you use FULLTEXT in [Boolean mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) you can insist that all your searched words appear in your result set. Have you tried that?

Comment: @O.Jones Yes, but as I mentioned in my question I am searching multiple tables. I need the words to appear in any table, not all words to appear in all tables.

Comment: can you share samples from the input table and the corresponding output you would get with your query against the expected one?

Comment: @lemon I've added a sample output from the query in my question.